# django rest framework: How to not allow validation on a nested serializer data?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I have a serializer `BookSerializer` of model `Book` with a nested `PageSerializer` of model `Page`. Updating of a `Book` instance involves deleting all its `Page` instances followed by creation of these `Page` instances, maybe with or without this updation involving some new data of pages or nothing or existing.

But my `Book` model holds a constraint where each `Book` instance can only have max `100` pages each. And the validation check is done inside the `PageSerializer`'s `validate` method. I have another reason to do this here:

```
def validate(self, attrs):
    #some logic here
    raise some error if book instance already has 100 pages or if it will have more than 100 pages when combined with new pages when added.
```

The update method definition of a serializer or say `BookSerializer` is:

```
def update(self, instance, validated_data):
    ...
    ...
```

So, the data being sent to update is already being validated and can be accessed as `validated_data` inside the `update` method.

Now, here's the problem. The nested serializer `PageSerializer` has a `validate` method which checks how many pages of that `Book` instance are already there and validates against them.

Let `B` be an instance of `Book` already having `100` pages. If I try to udate `B` without any changes, the data sent is still checked for validation in the `BookSerializer`, passing its pages data to `PageSerializer` and then finally passing the `validated_data` to `update(self, instance, val;idated_data)` method.

My questions are:

- How to delete all pages of `B` before validating data of pages sent for updation of `B`?
- Or How to bypass validation of the nested serializer? Only validate the serializer and will take care of the validation of the nested serializer inside the update method of the parent serializer before saving.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to you to delete pages in `update(**kwargs)` method of BookSerializer. In validation method of `PageSerializer` you should validate received data(you should not consider existed pages as a sequence you will **delete all them**). It is a case for only fully overriding pages of existed book. But when you want to update them you should also return `id`(you should add `id` in `PageSerializer` in order nested serializer can identify that you are updating an instance) of pages. So validation will be required in order to update.

Request body should be like this:

```
{
   'book_title': 'TITLE'
   'pages':[
           {'id': 3, 'title': 'TITLE', 'body': 'BODY'},
           {'title': 'TITLE', 'body': 'BODY'}, ...
    ]
    ....
}
class PageSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Page
        fields =['id', .....]

class Book(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    pages = PageSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Book
        fields = ['id', 'pages', ....]

    def validate_pages(self, values): # here values will be as [{...},{...},..]
        obj_list = list()
        for value in values:
            pk = value.pop('id', None)
            if pk:
               try:
                  page = Page.objects.get(pk=pk)
                  for k, v in value.items():
                      setattr(page, key, value)
                  obj_list.append(page)
               except Page.DoesNotExists():
                  # handle by yourself, skip or raise error
            else:
                obj_list.append(Page(**value))
         # here you can validate length also
         return obj_list
```

And in `create(self, validated_data)` and `update(self, instance, validated_data)` you get pages as object list. So you can delete using this:

```
pages = validated_data['pages']
page_ids = [page.pk for page in pages if page.pk] # it get all ids from list
if page_ids:
   Page.objects.filter(book=instance).exclude(pk__in=page_ids).delete() it can be applicable only for updating
```

And simple creation using bulk or iteration.

Comment: Ok. What if the `Book` has 100 pages and I pass along pages `1-9,20-50` ids for updation and aso include new pages to be created without having ids. Will that delete pages `10-19, 51-100`? And create new pages?

Comment: You can add `validate_pages(self, value)` to your `BookSerializer`. In this method you can manipulate your value and return it.

Comment: You are recreating the obj_list to its previous form. Please take a look. And this doesn't work as the order of validation is done as `nested_serializer` then `parent_serializer`. So the data mixed with ids and no ids of pages is first passed to `PageSerializer`, which identifies missing ids or any other validation and throws error before reaching your `validate_pages`.

Comment: Here you should move your validation to upper level(from `PageSerializer` to `BookSerializer`). Moreover, I think(I did not prove it for me) that nested serializer validation will work first than, parent serializer validation work. I come to this though from that if you add validation of length into `serializers.CharField` and add custom method validation length validation works first than validation function.

Comment: What do you mean by upper level? `PageSerilizer` validation( validate_<field> then validate) takes place before `BookSeriallizer` validation( validate_<field> then validate). Be it custom fields or anything else.

Comment: I mean from children serializer to parent serializer

Comment: How to do that?

Comment: I have added comment like  `# here you can validate length also`. You can add validation here

Comment: That violates DRY.

Comment: Anyway. Thanks for answering.

Comment: How it can violate DRY? Moreover, in page serializer you can validate only one page(item by item) not the whole list of items together so your validation for count will not work properly. If you are making request to database it is the worst way.